# Can I pass values from $http.get to another functions in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to learn AngularJS, and I'm wondering if I can do this or not?:
Here is my code:

```
(function() {
    function InfoController($scope,$element){
        $scope.items = data['data']; //data in Option controller
    }
    function OptionController($scope,$element,$http){
        $element.find(".list-group-item").click(function() {
          var a = $(this).text();
            $http({
                url: 'hand',
                method: "GET",
                params: {a: a},
            }).success(function(data){
               console.log(data['data'][0]);
            });
        });
    }
    angular.module('testModule', [])
        .controller('InfoController', InfoController)
        .controller('OptionController', OptionController);
})();
```

I'm new in AngularJS and I don't know how to pass values data['data'] from $http.get in OptionController to InfoController, so please tell me how can I do that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you would do so with a `service` [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)

```
app.service('dataService', function(http) {
  this.data;
  var self = this;

  this.getData = function() {
      return $http.get('/data').then(function(resp) {
        self.data = resp.data;
        return self.data
      })
  }
```

you would then pass in `dataService` to both controllers

```
$scope.data = dataService.getData()
```